# dmpmqcfg command not found in IBM MQ 7.0.1.6

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to get the Queue details created for 7.0.1.6.
I am running “dmpmqcfg” command
But the command is not found in my bin directory in IBM MQ 7.0.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

dmpmqcfg was added in V7.1 (previously, people used the MS03 saveqmgr SupportPac).

The MS03 SupportPac can be downloaded from the following page:

[WITHDRAWN: MS03: WebSphere MQ - Save Queue Manager object definitions using PCFs (saveqmgr)](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24000673)

The page also confirms the dmpmqcfg was added in v7.1

> Note: From MQ V7.1 onwards, the command dmpmqcfg is available in the
>   product. This is recommended instead of the use of MS03.